# Mysql SELECT IN, keep object parameter

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an array of "postal Code - distance" pair from a given postal code :

```
    [
       {
           postalCode : 18740
           distance : 25
       },
       {
           postalCode : 1999
           distance : 20
       },
       ...
     ]
```

I have a mysql table that look like this :

```
[   postalCode    -    data1     -    data2    ... ]
```

I'd like to find all the record that match the postal codes array displayed above and keep the distance associated with the postal code.

Is there a way to do that without parsing and looping through the results of a "SELECT * FROM table WHERE postalCode IN ()" query to add the distance information ?

Comment: so basically you want to discard from your array all the elements that don't exist in the DB?

Comment: Not really ! I'm interested by all the records in the db (several record can exist with the same postalCode) that match the postalCode in the array. I'm also interested by keeping the distance information for all the records that match.